# Checking if a specific field exists on an object in Thymeleaf page

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jsp, thymeleaf

```
<th:block th:each="item : ${mclist}" >
           <option th:if="${item.id}" th:value="${item.id}" th:text="${item}"></option>
           <option th:if="${item.id == null}" th:value="${item}" th:text="${item}"></option>
 </th:block>
```

The object 'item' can be any entity. Therefore it may or may not contain an 'id' field. The code presented here gives the following error when an entity does not contain 'id' field.

```
org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1008E: Property or field 'id' cannot be found on object of type 'java.lang.String' - maybe not public or not valid?
```

Is it possible  checking existence of id field in the 'item' object before extracting its value?

Comment: I don't think there is any native support in Thymeleaf for checking if a field exists on an object.  The best you're going to do is to write your own helper method that uses reflection to return `true` or `false` if an object has an id field, for that and use that in the Thymeleaf.  This is some pretty weird design though...

Answer (score 1):

Just use 'get'.

```
<th:block th:each="item : ${mclist}" >
    <option th:if="${item.get('id')} != null" th:value="${item.id}" th:text="${item}"></option>
</th:block>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use '?' operator. Something like this:

```
<div th:if="${item?.id}">
    <option th:value="${item.id}" th:text="${item}"></option>
</div>
```

Comment: Won't this still give you some form of _Property or field 'id' cannot be found on object_ error? We are not checking if the field's value is null. We want to check if the field _exists_ on the object, or not.

Comment: Thank to @ user3088166. I've tried "${item?.id}" approach. Still having the same error.